# Application Server connection status with Database Server

Tags: oracle, asp-classic, oracle10g

I have created more than one application servers that are connected to one DB server i.e. Oracle. So how do I identify which application server has accessed my DB.

Comment: how does your question relates to classic asp? do you connect to those db Servers  with classic asp? how?

Comment: @ulluoink:Classic asp is my language.I develop my webpage using Classic asp only.
I having more than one Application those are to be connected with one DB.

Comment: As usual @Sabarirajan a really detailed and concise question.

Answer (score 0):

you could add "Application Name=blah" to your Connection string when connecting with sqloledb.

then you could get that Application Name in your SQL Server with the APP_NAME() function.

that is all ms SQL Server logic, but probably you will find something similar for Oracle.

example Connection string:

```
CONTEXT_CONNSTRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" &_
           "Data Source=" & session("sqlserver") &_
           ";Initial Catalog=" & session("DB_VERWALTUNG") &_
           ";uid=" & session("sqlUsername") &_
           ";pwd=" & session("sqlPassword") &_
           ";Application Name=" & myAPPNAME & ";"
```

Comment: :Can you please add the sample code for my better understanding.

Comment: @Sabarirajan addded example connectionstring

Comment: :How to get the application name in Database.
If any Data Base queries??